# When i try to call the api data from axios i get 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, http-status-code-404

**code for HomeScreen.js to fetch the data:**
**Setting proxy in package.json**

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

I am trying to get the data from the local server as shown in the image below

[Error 404 that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtCIl.png)

[Image of data to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v5IO.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import data from '../data';
import axios from 'axios';

function HomeScreen(props) {

const [products, setProduct] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
       const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
       setProduct(data);
   }
   fetchData();
    return() => {

    };

}, [])

    return <ul className="products">
        {
            products.map(product =>
                <li key={product._id}>
                    <div className="product">
                        <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}><img className="product-image" src="/images/d1.jpg" alt="Product" />
                        </Link>
                        <div className="product-name"><Link to={'/product/' + product._id}> {product.name}</Link></div>
                        <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
                        <div className="product-price">{product.price}</div>
                        <div className="product-rating">{product.rating} Stars {product.numReviews}</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            )
        }

    </ul>
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: ports are different in both the screenshots

Comment: "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fetch data with relative path `/api/products` and if you see your error, browser is trying to fetch `http://localhost:3000/api/products`.
Change your fetch to this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");
```

or you should run your react app on port `5000`